# Имитация кликов мыши/тача в Unity

Tags: unity3d

подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно вызвать методы OnMouseUp и т.д. из кода?(вариант вызывать функции которые в них вызываются,не подходит. Чисто для windows видел подключение dll,а нужно чтобы и на телефоне имитировало тач)

Comment: не понял вопроса,но если нужны гайды по touchpad'y ,то они есть на ютубе:)

Comment: Нужно вызвать метод,который срабатывает при тапе/клике мыши по координатам input.GetKeyUP(keycode....)

Comment: почему MouseUp? Именно при отпускании клика/тапа должно сработать?

Comment: Попробуйте для начала опишите задачу, которую вы хотите решить этим способом. Возможно, существует иной вариант, либо вы не совсем верно формулируете вопрос.

Comment: Пишется менеджер для тестирования приложения,вносить изменения в проект нельзя(переписать куски где используются клики и тапы)

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь симулировать нажатия мышки через операционку:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class MouseOperations
{
    [Flags]
    public enum MouseEventFlags
    {
        LeftDown = 0x00000002,
        LeftUp = 0x00000004,
        MiddleDown = 0x00000020,
        MiddleUp = 0x00000040,
        Move = 0x00000001,
        Absolute = 0x00008000,
        RightDown = 0x00000008,
        RightUp = 0x00000010
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);      

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out MousePoint lpMousePoint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    public static void SetCursorPosition(int x, int y) 
    {
        SetCursorPos(x, y);
    }

    public static void SetCursorPosition(MousePoint point)
    {
        SetCursorPos(point.X, point.Y);
    }

    public static MousePoint GetCursorPosition()
    {
        MousePoint currentMousePoint;
        var gotPoint = GetCursorPos(out currentMousePoint);
        if (!gotPoint) { currentMousePoint = new MousePoint(0, 0); }
        return currentMousePoint;
    }

    public static void MouseEvent(MouseEventFlags value)
    {
        MousePoint position = GetCursorPosition();

        mouse_event
            ((int)value,
             position.X,
             position.Y,
             0,
             0)
            ;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MousePoint
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public MousePoint(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Если же нужно имитация тача

То ее можно сделать с помощью вот этого класса:

```
public class TouchCreator
{
    static BindingFlags flag = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    static Dictionary<string, FieldInfo> fields;

    object touch;

    public float deltaTime { get { return ((Touch)touch).deltaTime; } set { fields["m_TimeDelta"].SetValue(touch, value); } }
    public int tapCount { get { return ((Touch)touch).tapCount; } set { fields["m_TapCount"].SetValue(touch, value); } }
    public TouchPhase phase { get { return ((Touch)touch).phase; } set { fields["m_Phase"].SetValue(touch, value); } }
    public Vector2 deltaPosition { get { return ((Touch)touch).deltaPosition; } set { fields["m_PositionDelta"].SetValue(touch, value); } }
    public int fingerId { get { return ((Touch)touch).fingerId; } set { fields["m_FingerId"].SetValue(touch, value); } }
    public Vector2 position { get { return ((Touch)touch).position; } set { fields["m_Position"].SetValue(touch, value); } }
    public Vector2 rawPosition { get { return ((Touch)touch).rawPosition; } set { fields["m_RawPosition"].SetValue(touch, value); } }

    public Touch Create()
    {
        return (Touch)touch;
    }

    public TouchCreator()
    {
        touch = new Touch();
    }

    static TouchCreator()
    {
        fields = new Dictionary<string, FieldInfo>();
        foreach (var f in typeof(Touch).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
        {
            fields.Add(f.Name, f);
            Debug.Log("name: " + f.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Более полный код с реализацией имитации тача мышкой находится по линке: https://romanluks.eu/blog/how-to-simulate-touch-with-mouse-in-unity/

так что можно глубже копнуть об использовании кода.